# Why has the color gone from the last seen timestamp?

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, meta

The 'last seen' date on the profile page seems to have lost its color. This makes me sad. Let me illustrate:

[image]

I really like the color because it tells me stuff without me actually having to read. Please bring back color to mSE.

Comment: we hate color like we hate fun!

Comment: @bluefeet But... blue is nice, right?